# How to get IP address of Computer, in which the node js server runs, to use in react application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I wanna get the IP address of the computer that the node js server runs in, in order to use the correct URLs of the server inside React application.

for example when I fetch a "http://localhost:<port>/api" from another device in the same network it doesn't work.

I tried to provide the computer IP address manually, but after sometime, a day or two, the IP changes and then I have to open provide the IP address again.

so, I'm asking if there's a way to provide the IP address dynamically to React application?

Comment: if this is just 'dev' issue, most of the cli apis that are used to launch the other services should ALL allow CLI config of port# using '- p' or some such in the CLI/ script expression used to start them. This control of the respective ports may allow u the reconfig your federated services running on localhost in dev.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the Node networkInterfaces  Out Of  the Box feature, or use a package that handles parsing request and extracting data for you.

```
const os = require('os');
const networkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
console.log(networkInterfaces);
```

If you do not want to parse the response yourself - have a look at highly popular package: request-ip.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip

```
const requestIp = require('request-ip');
 
// inside middleware handler
const ipMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    const clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req); 
    next();
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think this is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to connect React with Node.js API, the problem is that  I have to write the URLs of the node.js server inside React, like "http://localhost:<port>", now localhost won't work if I'm using the app from another device than the one running the server, and when I tried to write my computer's IP address it worked, but a day later, I don't know why, the IP address changed, so I had to go to change each url which is a burden I think I can avoid with some way

Comment: Also, I wrote a script in my react application to retrieve the IP address with Node networkInterfaces, but then I realized that this will only retrieve the client's IP address, not the server's IP address. If I'm wrong here, and there's a way to retrieve the server's IP address, like running the script with "npm start" script, then please tell me how I can do it.

Comment: your IP changes unless you pay for a static IP to provider. Usually they have a small charge fee to provide you a static one. This is for the IP the rest of the world see you. You can check with it with some free services like : https://whatismyipaddress.com/.

In your house - local IP - is the router Configuration - that you want to change for specific devices. By default is dynamic in most of the routers/access points - but can be reserved if you login into router usually on local IP ending with .254

Comment: thank you so much for taking effort to answer my questions. I'm not using a local IP ending with .254 so I guess it will continue changing arbitrarily. I found a simple solution to my problem which is to proxy all the urls I'm using in my react app by adding a "proxy" key to package.json holding the node server url and whenever my IP changes I only edit this key once and restart the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone facing the same problem, I found a simple solution which is to specify a "proxy" in package.json file of the React application:

in package.json file

```
...
"proxy": "http://192.xxx.xx.xxx:<port>"
...
```

this way you're telling react to proxy the requests to the backend server when making a request for example to "/api/v1" instead of specifying the whole url like this "http://192.xxx.xx.xxx:<port>/api/v1"

and whenever the IP changes you just edit the "proxy" value and restart the dev server.